# Sales Forecasting – how to treat missing prices during public holidays?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I want to forecast sales volume for an item as a function of some exognous features including the price of the item (daily data with daily and annual seasonality).

Sales volume is zero during public holidays. To account for zero sales on public holidays I include a public holiday dummy.

I am not sure how to treat missing prices during public holidays. Intuitively, it seems wrong to set the missing price to some reasonable value (e.g. previous day price) as this would distort the link between sales volume and price.

What would be an appropriate approach to handle this problem?

Comment: Why not just drop the public holidays from your analysis altogether, as in, remove them from the data set?  After all, if there are no sales, and that's because they are public holidays, there's no information about the relationship between the exogenous features and sales in those records either.

Comment: If your analysis identified anomalies the "0 sales" would be automatically adjusted to reflect the price value ... probably the most recent price

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments! jbowman's suggestion to drop public holidays from the analysis seems more straightforward to me than IrishStat's idea of anomalie detection. What would be the advantage of one over the other? One disadvantage of removing public holidays seems that you cannot define anymore a regular frequency (e.g. 6 for weekly seasonality excluding Sunday) required for certain time series methods. However, since I can include seasonal dummies this shouldn't be too much of a constraint I hope.